# Imwarp Image Simulink Matlab Function Block Variable Size

Tags: matlab, function, variables, size, simulink

I wrote a function that transforms an input image to another image size with imwarp. This function is implemented in a Matlab Function Block in Simulink. Since the size of the input signal changes, I have to define a variable signal size. I did this (see picture). Nevertheless I get an error message. Can anyone help me here?

[Parameter of output signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kknz5.png)

Size of 3 input images R,G,B: 1080 1920; Size output image should be: 960 1440 3

**I get following error:**

Simulink cannot propagate the variable-size mode from the output port 1 of '..../MATLAB Function3' to the input port 1 of '.../To Multimedia File2'. This input port expects a fixed-size mode. The variable-size mode originates from '.../MATLAB Function3/ SFunction '. Examine the configurations of '.../To Multimedia File2' for one of the following scenarios: 1) the block does not support variable-size signals; 2) the block supports variable-size signals but needs to be configured for them.

Comment: You'll almost certainly find that the reason for the error is due to item 1) in the suggested list - that is `the [To Multimedia] block does not support variable-size signals`.

Comment: Can you tell me how to get the signal back as a constant after the Malab Function Block so I can save it as a video? The image size after the Matlab Function Block should be constant.

Comment: Try adding a selector before "To Multimedia" that selects the required frame size.

Comment: Make the output of the MATLAB Function block a constant of the largest size you will ever have, and just embed (i.e. copy) your actual images (as created by imwarp) into an appropriate submatrix (of the constant sized output matrix).